# DNN Repository module on Azure website

Tags: iis, azure, dotnetnuke, filepath, azure-web-app-service

I have to migrate existing website to Windows Azure hosted as Web Site.
Problem is that it uses Repository module and it stops working.
when i sign in as a host i see error using repository module

*A critical error has occurred. Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Portals\0\Repository' is denied.*

Well i know that this path is totally wrong in azure.

According to http://support.powerdnn.com/kb/a332/error-access-denied-when-using-the-repository-module.aspx

i have to change the path manually in DB to current path but
what is the path in azure.

Azure website in configuration page also say me that there is virtual directory:

**/** -> **site\wwwroot**

but how to use that because */\Portals\0\Repository* doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Ah i found that

according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/5ae6c196-253a-4927-bb5a-da0d96245729/is-the-physical-path-to-my-website-always-dhomesitewwwroot?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

home path is always
*D:\home\site\wwwroot*

So correct path is then **D:\home\site\wwwroot\Portals\0\Repository**
Tested this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before and it's not a problem of the Azure environment (also happens if you move the website to another location), is just that the Repository module (http://dnnrepository.codeplex.com/) is storing the full local paths in the database instead of storing the relative path to the App. BTW, as an enhancement, it should use the DNN's file system in order to take full advantage of Folder Providers, etc.

**Note that hardcoding the path in the database can end in a future error if MS decides to change the root folder for Azure Websites**.

The correct thing here would be:
 - log this as an issue in the Repository Project to allow the project coordinators to schedule the fix (http://dnnrepository.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic);
 - if you want to collaborate with the Community and this Project in particular, you could also do a pull request with your own fix. Open Source rulez :)